# Shoppe gem each method on product categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, rubygems

Just wondering if anyone with any experience with Shoppe know how to call an each method on product categories?

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
<% Shoppe::ProductCategory.each do |prod| %>
   <li><%= prod.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

but I'm getting an undefined method error. Is there some special method that I'm missing? `Shoppe::ProductCategory.all` and `Shoppe::ProductCategory.first.name` both have no problems.

Thanks!

**solved**

Beautiful, @zoran, beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting it to this instead:

```
 <% Shoppe::ProductCategory.all.each do |prod| %>
   <li><%= prod.name %></li>
 <% end %>
```

You need to call `all` on the `Shoppe::ProductCategory` to be able to iterate over the collection.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi there, I can't seem to figure out what is the variable for the categories path, I've tried `product_categories_path` but it doesn't work.